# Looping Through Similar Variable Names C++

Tags: c++, loops

**Problem**: I'm trying to loop through consecutive variables that has an increasing index for it's last character. It shares the beginning portion which is "aNumber". **What I tried** I used sprintf_s to index the index i on to a variable named, "aNumber" but that led to a big number being incremented by 1.

**Expected output**: The number 1, 2, and 3 should be printed on separate lines.

Here's what I tried

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    int aNumber1 = 1;
    int aNumber2 = 2;
    int aNumber3 = 3;

    char buffer[50];

    for (int i = 1; i < 4; ++i)
    {
        int formattedNumber = sprintf_s(buffer, "%d%d", "aNumber", i); //Format "aNumber" with the number. Ex: "aNumber1"
        std::cout << buffer << std::endl; //Print the buffer to the screen
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Actual unexpected results**

[image: Unexpected Results]

Comment: place them in a map, vector, list

Comment: This is what arrays are for.  Put those three separate variables into a single array.

Comment: This is not how it works. That's what arrays are made for.

Comment: Variable names disappear after compilation (unless you compile in debug mode).

Comment: An array would be the only way to do this is what you guys are saying right?

Comment: Variable names exist for the convenience of the programmer only. All the program cares about is where in memory to look. All those nice descriptive names vanish and are replaced either with an address or an offset from an address by the time the linker's done putting the program together.

Comment: If you know at compile time how many of these variables you have use an array or `std::array`. If you don't know how many, use a `std::vector`. If they are scattered rather than a nice, contiguous block, consider using a `std::map` or `std::unordered_map`

Comment: is that code even correct? second argument of `sprintf_s` is supposed to be the size of `buffer`, not the format string. Unless I'm misreading something...

Comment: `sprintf_s` is a weird case. You have Microsoft's `sprintf_s` and you have the one defined in the Standard's Annex... Uhhh.. Can't remember which annex. Anyway both are different and Microsoft has a few overloads to make it even more messy.

Comment: @searchengine27 The first argument is the size in `sprintf_s` for the one I used. Not the second argument. I based my code off of this reference http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sprintf/

Comment: @searchengine27 [Here we go](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/sprintf-s-sprintf-s-l-swprintf-s-swprintf-s-l?view=vs-2019). Fifth one down. MS has a template that infers the size of the buffer from an array argument.